# FloatingButton to Toolbar animation

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, material-design

i'm using a floating button on my application but i want to do the conversion to toolbar like show on the video, somebody have a sample for that?, if don't have don't worry i'm start to develop but i want a guide, thanks

i have this option:

```
ViewCompat.animate(view).setDuration(1000).scaleYBy(1).scaleXBy(1).start();
```

or this option:

```
 ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionView, EXTRA_IMAGE);
```

[sample video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsVWZpVkdpb09qREE/components-buttons-fab-transition_toolbar_01_xhdpi_002.webm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded the solution, i don't have the same result, but works for me, i post my code:

```
private void animateBottomToolbar() {
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet().setDuration(500L);
    if(bottomToolbarShowing) {
        //hide toolbar
        set.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toolbarBottom, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.0f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addButton, "scaleY", 0.0f, 1.0f)
        );

        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                toolbarBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                animation.removeAllListeners();
            }
        });

        set.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        set.start();
        bottomToolbarShowing = false;
    } else {
        //show toolbar
        if (floatMenuOpen) animateFloatingMenu();
        set.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toolbarBottom, "scaleY", 0.0f, 1.0f),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addButton, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.0f)
        );

        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolbarBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animation.removeAllListeners();
                inflateMenuOnBottomToolbar();
            }
        });
        set.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        set.start();
        bottomToolbarShowing = true;
    }

}
```